# null text when the textbox mode changes mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm  trying to change the `TextMode` field using a button. During this operation the text gets cleared

```
 protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
  string  constring2 = passwordtxt.Text;
    if (passwordtxt.TextMode == TextBoxMode.Password)
    {
        passwordtxt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert(+constring)</script>");

    }
   else 
    {
        passwordtxt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Inserted succussfully')</script>");

    }
    passwordtxt.Text = constring2;
}
```

Comment: Is it a problem to read the content of the textbox and readd it after the mode change?

Comment: can u show sample code

Comment: @VenkateshVenky See my answer

Comment: Is `ViewState` enabled for the password field?

Comment: @DiskJunky not.

Comment: Well, that's likely your issue. Unless `ViewState` is turned on, the control contents are not preserved between postbacks

Comment: Ya i enabled but i am getting same issue.